# Global Platform Java Card Secure Channel Example

Tags: javacard, apdu, globalplatform

I'm struggling for a long time. I need to create secure channel from Desktop App to JavaCard. I found GlobalPlatform http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/gp22/ but I can't get it working. I know how to react when I have a secure channel ( use it ) but strugling to create it. I know I should create Key on my desktop app then somehow send InitUpdate APDU, then create ExtAuth APDU and then it should work? I know I'm lost so if anybody have some example or something I'll be so glad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Assuming you want to implement the client-side of the communication)

The SCP protocols used to establish secure channel are precisely defined in *GlobalPlatform Card Specifications*,
available [here](https://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp), specifically:

- **SCP01 / SCP02 / SCP10** in *GlobalPlatform Card Specification v2.3* (appendices D,E,F)
- **SCP03** in *Card Technology Secure Channel Protocol '03' Card Specification v2.2 – Amendment D V1.1.1*

You can have a look at [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/3067bd530f674176a83472197d9fecfe56168628/library/src/main/java/pro/javacard/gp/GPSession.java#L362) (java) or [GPShell](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/globalplatform/src/globalplatform.c#l3772) (C) for some source code.

Good luck!

---

PS: The `org.globalplatform` [API](https://globalplatform.org/specs-library/globalplatform-card-api-org-globalplatform/) you mention in your post is used inside the card and allows javacard applets to use keys stored in the SD for secure communication/authentication.